# Populate state with values from autocomplete (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, autocomplete

I have a component with inputfields and a button which is disabled unless the correct values are entered in the inputfields. This works fine but when chrome autocompletes those values on page load, the state isn't changed and thus the button stays disabled. If you click inside the form or change a value the state changes correctly.

How can I get the value from autocomplete when the component load? Autocomplete doesn't trigger the onChange or onBlur events and autocomplete="off" doesn't work either. (also I'd prefer not to turn off autocomplete anyways)

Comment: Check if any of the fields already have a value after the render event of the component? And if so, update state accordingly. Each browser handles autofill differently, so we can't hook up an event that will get triggered. webkit based browsers will add a class to the elements that got autofilled that you can detect, but that won't work on non-webkit based browsers.

Comment: Trying to do that but how can I get those values? In componentDidMount() the value is still ''. Refs don't work either. Maybe I could hack it with setTimout but that seems wrong. With plain old js in the chrome console I can access those values but not in react.

Comment: You can get the actual value of the HTML nodes. So I would querySelector all the input nodes and compare their values with the values in the state so that the state of the component matches the state of the HTML inputs again.

Comment: thanks for your help. When i acces the dom node from react (even in a timeout) it doesn't have a value (i tried the normal document.querySelector and with refs). As it seems this issue is open since 2014 and still not fixed: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1159
I guess leave the button enabled for now and make it disabled once the form is changed (and the values are not correct)

Comment: We can't solve it since autocomplete does not work the same way in all browsers. So we have to fix it the ugly way by comparing values until there's a standardized way browsers handle autocomplete. But that will take another couple years afaik, there isn't a spec being prepared to solve this. So I understand that facebook isn't going to put non-production-ready things into react.

Comment: alright thanks! kinda surprising that this is still an issue but yeah I see your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently came across this problem while working on my login page. After a bit of research, I came across [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1159#issuecomment-506584346) reported on the ReactJS github. To quote the key part:

> If we are able to access autofilled values once the page loads, it would become very easy to write malicious code to extract information on a form intended for phishing. Giving the user no chance to react. Probably part of the reason why autocomplete="off" is ignored by browsers.
>
> To overcome this problem we need to:
>
> 1. Accept the fact that we won't (and never will) have access to autofilled values when the DOM node mounts
> 2. Embrace the security concerns which are brought up by the browsers

tl;dr - It's intentional for security reasons, and it's better to validate the inputs upon submit instead.